# Eclipse: custom updateSite not displaying

Tags: eclipse

I created a custom plug-in in Eclipse having views in it. It is running normally when run as Eclipse Application. I created an updateSite for it and installed the plugin through local server after keeping the folder in the root directory. After restarting the Eclipse, the option in `Window->Show View->Other->MyPlugin` is not coming while it was coming while running as Eclipse Application.

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Can you check that the plugin is actually installed? You can do this by going to About, then clicking on Installation Details and seeing what features you have installed.